# JQuery : trigger a click on an Ajax generated HTML's

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Please feel free to edit title or description if I'm not making myself clear.

Big question today : what exactly does `alert('foobar');` on DOM ?!

This is my problem : I have a BIG TREE in database to fetch (3 levels). So in my `<form>` I load it gradually, with AJAX (you can see it on the picture)[image: HCI]
Here is my code (simplified) - I am really sorry to paste a large part of code, but all is needed - :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // generate the CAT box
        $("input[name='or-idgd']").change(function(){
            var idgd = this.value;
            $.post(GLOBAL_HOST+"ajax.php", {'myarg':idgd},
              function(data){
                var form = '';
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                form += '<div>';
                for (var i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++) {
                  form += '<label for="'+obj[i].id_cat+'_cat">';
                  form += '<input id="'+obj[i].id_cat+'_cat" type="radio" name="or-idcat"';
                  form += 'value="'+obj[i].id_cat+'" >';
                  form += obj[i].cat_name+'</label>';
                }
                form += '</div>';
                $("div#box_cat").append(form);
              }
            );
        });
          // generate the COMP box
        $("input[name='or-idcat']").change(function(){
          var idcat = this.value;
          $.post(GLOBAL_HOST+"ajax.php", {'myarg2':idcat},
            function(data){
              $("div#box_comp").empty();
              var form = '';
              var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              form += '<div>';
              for (var i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++) {
               form += '<label for="'+obj[i].id_comp+'_comp">';
               form += '<input id="'+obj[i].id_comp+'_comp" type="radio" name="or-idcomp"';
               form += ' value="'+obj[i].id_comp+'">';
               form += obj[i].competence_nom+'</label>';
              }
              form += '</div>';
              $("div#box_comp").append(form);
            }
          );
        }));
<?php   /*** THIS IS THE INTERESTED PART - rebulding the tree cf screenshot ***/
        // When the form is submitted :
        if (!empty($_POST['or-idgd'])) { ?>
            $('#<?php echo $_POST['or-idgd']; ?>_gd').trigger('click');
<?php       if (!empty($_POST['or-idcat'])) { ?>
                //alert('before');
                $('#<?php echo $_POST['or-idcat']; ?>_cat').trigger('click');
                //alert('after');
<?php           if (!empty($_POST['or-idcomp'])) { ?>
                    $('#<?php echo $_POST['or-idcomp']; ?>_comp').prop('checked', true);
<?php           }
            }
        } ?>
    }); // document.ready
</script>
```

The code above works fine. But, when I submit the form, I rebuild the tree in JQuery, using `.trigger()` to **simulate** a click. And here we are : like this, this is not working. Only the cat_box is created (thanks to the gd_box built in PHP), *ie* only the first `.trigger('click')` works. Yes, I know, I think I can rebuild it in PHP, but I prefer not to..

**But brace yourself** : if I uncommented the two `alert()`, others `.trigger()` works too, and I can have what I want (cf screenshot).

**Two questions :**

1. How the hell `alert()` allow Jquery to reconsider DOM ? Ok, I get it, thanks.
2. How can I fix it ? (I tried `.live()`, `.on()`, etc ...)

Comment: `alert` causes the browser to halt, which sometimes gives it enough time to download resources(images) or to receive an ajax request at a different time than it would normally without the alert. It is usually better to debug without the use of `alert` by using the `console`.

Comment: Most likely you are triggering the click event too early.

Comment: @Kevin B : true, good advice to favor `console` instead of `alert()`. Thanks for the explanation of the `alert()` behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alert halts the browser, which in your case gives the oportunity to:

1. complete the ajax-request
2. insert the new elements into the dom*

You need to add some functionality to make you `trigger()` wait for the last calls to complete, so it actually can be executed on your element.
Usually this is done, by handing a callback to the function which is executes once it is completed.

```
function doStuff(callback){
   // do Stuff

   callback();
}
function doMoreStuff(){
   // do more stuff after doStuff() is done
}

// do stuff and after(!) that do more stuff
function doStuff(doMoreStuff);
```

***** actually this is put into the eventqueue and is scheduled before the rest of your code. During the alert, JS in the GUI-thread is completely stalled. The evaluation of the ajax-callback is scheduled before the rest of your code (not sure whether you can rely on that).

EDIT:

Your code could look like this:

```
$("input[name='or-idgd']").change(function(e,callback){
   // first parameter (e) is always the event object
   ...
   // if this eventhandler is called with a callback function given
   // execute it in the end of your function
   if(callback){callback()}
}

// and your modified trigger:

$('#<?php echo $_POST['or-idgd']; ?>_gd').trigger('change',
      // handing over the second trigger as a callback function
      // which gets executed after the first one is ready
      function(){$('#<?php echo $_POST['or-idcat']; ?>_cat').trigger('click');}
  );
```

See a minimalistic example of the [working callback functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/FJQPL/). The first time, change is triggered with a callback, all subsequent times it's called normally.

Comment: The only thing is, I don't see anywhere in his code where he is actually making an ajax request, neither of those change events are being triggered.

Comment: @Kevin B : Before submiting the `<form>`, I browse the tree, and select a GD line, a CAT line, and a COMP line. And when the page is reloaded (after submit), the ìnterested part` of my quoted code is re-creating the tree. By simulate a click with `trigger`, I trigger the `change()` event !

Comment: @Ash_ aditionally you could build your own event-queue and push those trigger actions into an array. Then you can execute one and once it's finished, pop the next and execute it until your queue is empty.

Comment: Hey, good idea. Do you have any example of a manual event-queue ?

Comment: well, for your two ajax calls an event queue might be overkill, but you could alter the methods accordingly. I will edit my post, since there is not enough space in the comment-section.

Comment: First, the `if(callback){callback()}` create an error, because it is always true, even when I click on an item (the `type of` callback is object, no matter if the function is called by the trigger (and with an efective callback fonction) or normally, by clic on the list.

Second, even if I thought it will work, it didn't : the trigger placed as a callback fonction is never called (a console.log do nothing).

But it was a great idea !

Comment: well, I missed the point that the first param handed over is the [event-object](http://api.jquery.com/change/), thus it should be `function(e,callback)`.

Comment: Ok, no more error. But now, `callback` is always undefined, so it is never executed. We do not need to write `e` in the callback triger function ?

Comment: change the trigger to trigger on `change` and not `click`. (Like in my edit).

Comment: I test something strange : `$('#<?php echo $_POST['or-idgd']['value'][0]; ?>_gd').trigger('change', get_cat(<?php echo $_POST['or-idcat']['value']; ?>));` and my console.log tell me that the function `get_cat()` is called BEFORE the trigger change on _gd, even if I remove the `if(callback){callback()}` ! It is executed alone ?

Comment: You need to wrap a function around it, else it gets executed first and after that the return value is passed to your trigger - common mistake;) `.trigger('change', function(){get_cat(<?php echo $_POST['or-idcat']['value']; ?>)});`

Comment: Ok, I get it :) Well, I am close to the solution : I succeed to build the third box (COMP), but with the `trigger('change')`, it dont check the button. But I have some ideas ;) I will keep you in touch !

Comment: Well, it is not possible in my case to check the radio... So I think I will give up, and rebuild my select in PHP. (hate code replication ><)